# How do I find out which Account is associated with a specific ContentDocument?

Tags: trigger, attachment, contentdocument

When the user attaches a file to an account, this triggers the ContentDocument trigger. What logic should I put in the ContentDocument trigger to have it find the associated account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find that with the help of `ContentDocumentLink`. Use below query:

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId, ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId='0690K00000JFYNFQA5' AND ShareType
```

- `ContentDocumentId` can be filtered from `Trigger.new` .
- If document is uploaded against only 1 record, then you will get 2 links from above query. 1 against user and 2 against record (account in your case). `LinkedEntityId` will give you the `Id` of user and record in those two links .
- If the document is shared among multiple records, you will get as many links and you need to write logic for processing the record Ids.

---

**Added based on comments:**

It appears from the document record page, you can share it with only other users. For sharing with other records, You can do a DML on link as below:

```
ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
    LinkedEntityId='0010K00001eKzKgQAK',
    ShareType='V',
    ContentDocumentId='0690K00000JFYNFQA5'
);

insert link;
```

Run above in anonymous code with any record Id in `LinkedEntityId` and go to that record. You will see the file in its related list.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible for there to be multiple account IDs, or will there always be one?

Comment: You can share the document with any sObject you want (including another account) - so, as highlighted in answer, you will get as many links

Comment: Could you give me the steps for how to share a document with multiple accounts? I'm not seeing the option to do that. (I only see an option to share with other users.)

Comment: added in answer